# Drop-Down Menu Disconnects

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css

I have a navbar at the top of all my [pages](http://enc0deweb.com). When the browser width is less than 40em, the links in the navbar become a hamburger. When clicked, the hamburger turns green and drops down a menu by using the jQuery toggleClass function. On all the browsers I've tried (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and iOS) except for iOS, the hamburger works properly. However, on iOS, the hamburger turns green, moves off the header, and the drop-down menu is disconnected from the header.

HTML:

```
<span class="mobile-nav">
    <div class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
        <div>
            <a href="#" id="hamburger" onclick="return false;">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="responsive-menu">
        <div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <a href="/about">About</a><div class="spacer"></div>
            <a href="/why">Why Enc0de</a><div class="spacer"></div>
            <a href="/contact">Contact</a><div class="spacer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.mobile-nav {
    float: right;
}
.responsive-menu {
    display: none;
}
#hamburger {
    margin: .813em 1.25em 0em 0em;
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.125em;
    float: right;
    background-image: url('/images/hamburger.gif');
    background-size: 2.5em 2.125em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#hamburger.expand {
    background-image:url('/images/green_hamburger.gif'); 
}
div.expand {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: rgba(247, 247, 247, 1);
    top: .843em;
    right: 0em;
    border-style: hidden;
    border-width: .063em;
    border-radius: 0em 0em 0em .5em;
    box-shadow: 0 .188em .375em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
div.expand div {
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
}
div.expand div a {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0em .5em 0em .75em;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    -o-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    transition:.3s;
}
div.expand div a:hover {
    color: #00c900;
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
    $( '.menu-btn' ).click(function(){
    $('.responsive-menu').toggleClass('expand')
    $('#hamburger').toggleClass('expand')
    })
});
```

After many hours of research and attempted debugging, I am still completely confused. Any help, suggestions, or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is make an accordian menu. I've never seen it done using strictly divs, but what you might want to consider using is an unordered list ( < ul > < / ul > ) with the list items ( < li > < / li > ) on display:none, using jquery to find and display the list within the ul that you clicked on. Speaking of jquery code, you haven't attached yours, so please do.

Watch the tutorial via this link to get an example of what you should do, as it provides not only html and css code, but jquery code as well for an accordian menu: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/vertical-accordion-menu-using-jquery-css3

Comment: Thanks for answering. I looked at the accordion link, however, that's not what I'm trying to do. The menu isn't supposed to slide down, but to appear. It already works successfully on computer, but not on iOS. Here a [link](http://enc0deweb.com). (By the way, I added my jQuery). @Star